# How to create a new box beside the original one that I had created?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have been working on a project which demonstrates the arithmetic sequence. The user inputs the starting term of the sequence, the difference, and how many terms they want to generate, and the code will generate the sequence. I wanted to place each term in a block like this:
[image: A picture of the Arithmetic Squence]

However, the example shown above was a hard-coded version. I want the sequence to generate by itself and can be customized by the user. However, I ran into an issue: The new block that had been generated replaces the old block. Is there any way for me to generate new ones instead of replacing them?

Code:

```js
var t0, difference, boxedNums, numOfTerms, redCircle, redTriangle, redRectangle, blueCircle, blueTriangle, blueRectangle;
redCircle = "<img src='imgs/negativeOne.png'>";
redTriangle = "<img src='imgs/negativeTen.png'>";
redRectangle = "<img src='imgs/negativeHundred.png'";
blueCircle = "<img src='imgs/one.png'";
blueTriangle = "<img src='imgs/ten.png'";
blueRectangle = "img src='imgs/hundred.png'";

function genTn() {
  t0 = document.getElementById("t0").value;
  difference = document.getElementById("d").value;
  numOfTerms = document.getElementById("tn").value;
  var tn;
  document.getElementById('buildButton').style.display = 'none';
  for (n = 0; n < numOfTerms; n++) {
    tn = t0 * 1 + difference * n;
    setTimeout(buildNextOne, 1500 * n, n, tn);
  }
  setTimeout(showButton, 1500 * numOfTerms);
}

function buildNextOne(n, tn) {
  // console.log('t' + n + " = " + tn);
  document.getElementById("boxArea").innerHTML = '<div class="col-sm-4 col-md-2"><span id="boxed" class="center">t<sub>' + n + '</sub><span class="tn">' + tn + '</span></span></div>'
}

function showButton() {
  document.getElementById('buildButton').style.display = '';
}
```

```css
.center {
  text-align: center;
}

#constantsControl {
  background-color: palegreen;
  border-radius: 10%;
}

#equation {
  background-color: yellow;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 10%;
}

body {
  background-color: lightblue;
}

#formula {
  background-color: yellow;
}

span {
  display: block;
}

#boxed {
  border: 1px solid;
}

.tn {
  font-size: 3em;
}

#invisible {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-GJzZqFGwb1QTTN6wy59ffF1BuGJpLSa9DkKMp0DgiMDm4iYMj70gZWKYbI706tWS" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

  <title>Assignment 10a2</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="formula">
    Formula: <br> t
    <sub>n</sub> = t<sub>0</sub> + d*n <br>
    <br> t
    <sub>0</sub>
    <input type="range" min="-50" max="50" value="0" id="t0" class="slider">
    <br> d
    <input type="range" min="-50" max="50" value="0" id="d" class="slider">
    <br> n
    <input type="range" min="1" max="20" value="10" id="tn" class="slider">
    <br>
    <button id="buildButton" style="display:''" type="button" class="btn btn-warning" onclick="genTn()">Generate</button>
  </div>

  <br>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="row" id="boxArea">
    </div>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.6/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-wHAiFfRlMFy6i5SRaxvfOCifBUQy1xHdJ/yoi7FRNXMRBu5WHdZYu1hA6ZOblgut" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B0UglyR+jN6CkvvICOB2joaf5I4l3gm9GU6Hc1og6Ls7i6U/mkkaduKaBhlAXv9k" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="10a2.js"></script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will add new box beside old one.
Changes made in buildNextOne() function.

```js
var t0, difference, boxedNums, numOfTerms, redCircle, redTriangle, redRectangle, blueCircle, blueTriangle, blueRectangle;
redCircle = "<img src='imgs/negativeOne.png'>";
redTriangle = "<img src='imgs/negativeTen.png'>";
redRectangle = "<img src='imgs/negativeHundred.png'";
blueCircle = "<img src='imgs/one.png'";
blueTriangle = "<img src='imgs/ten.png'";
blueRectangle = "img src='imgs/hundred.png'";

function genTn() {
  t0 = document.getElementById("t0").value;
  difference = document.getElementById("d").value;
  numOfTerms = document.getElementById("tn").value;
  var tn;
  document.getElementById('buildButton').style.display = 'none';
  for (n = 0; n < numOfTerms; n++) {
    tn = t0 * 1 + difference * n;
    setTimeout(buildNextOne, 1500 * n, n, tn);
  }
  setTimeout(showButton, 1500 * numOfTerms);
}

function buildNextOne(n, tn) {
 
  
  var nodediv=document.createElement("div");
  
  nodediv.setAttribute('style','col-md-2; margin-right: 10px;');
  nodediv.innerHTML='<span id="boxed" class="center">t<sub>' + n + '</sub><span class="tn">' + tn + '</span></span>';
  document.getElementById("boxArea").appendChild(nodediv);
}

function showButton() {
  document.getElementById('buildButton').style.display = '';
}
```

```css
.center {
  text-align: center;
}

#constantsControl {
  background-color: palegreen;
  border-radius: 10%;
}

#equation {
  background-color: yellow;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 10%;
}

body {
  background-color: lightblue;
}

#formula {
  background-color: yellow;
}

span {
  display: block;
}

#boxed {
  border: 1px solid;
}

.tn {
  font-size: 3em;
}

#invisible {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-GJzZqFGwb1QTTN6wy59ffF1BuGJpLSa9DkKMp0DgiMDm4iYMj70gZWKYbI706tWS" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

  <title>Assignment 10a2</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="formula">
    Formula: <br> t
    <sub>n</sub> = t<sub>0</sub> + d*n <br>
    <br> t
    <sub>0</sub>
    <input type="range" min="-50" max="50" value="0" id="t0" class="slider">
    <br> d
    <input type="range" min="-50" max="50" value="0" id="d" class="slider">
    <br> n
    <input type="range" min="1" max="20" value="10" id="tn" class="slider">
    <br>
    <button id="buildButton" style="display:''" type="button" class="btn btn-warning" onclick="genTn()">Generate</button>
  </div>

  <br>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="row" id="boxArea">
    </div>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.6/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-wHAiFfRlMFy6i5SRaxvfOCifBUQy1xHdJ/yoi7FRNXMRBu5WHdZYu1hA6ZOblgut" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B0UglyR+jN6CkvvICOB2joaf5I4l3gm9GU6Hc1og6Ls7i6U/mkkaduKaBhlAXv9k" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="10a2.js"></script>
</body>
```